UV showing warning of incorrect Python version
I'm using uv to manage my Python version and dependencies in a project I'm working on.
When I run uv run pytest to test said project I get the following:
============================================================================= test session starts =============================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.12.5, pytest-8.3.3, pluggy-1.5.0
...
(test output)
...
============================================================================== warnings summary ===============================================================================
../../../../../usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi/core.py:36
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi/core.py:36: DeprecationWarning: path is deprecated. Use files() instead. Refer to https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#migrating-from-legacy for migration advice.
    _CACERT_CTX = get_path("certifi", "cacert.pem")

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html

I don't understand what's going on.
First it says it's using Python3.12.5 which is the version I specified for this project, but then the warning is coming from Python3.9 ?
How can I get rid of this message?

Please provide a [mre].

Do you have the Python version defined in a .python-version file or in a pyproject.toml?
